# Android How to center the textview

Tags: android, textview, android-linearlayout, android-xml

I have tried tons of combinations, but my "sectionTitle textview" goes always to the left next to the "sectionOptionsButton button". I want to center it between both buttons horizontal and vertically.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/BackGroundColor"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:scaleType="center" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mLlayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:background="@color/BlueOcean"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sectionOptionsButton"
            android:layout_width="33dp"
            android:layout_height="33dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:layout_gravity="left"            
            android:background="@drawable/adddatabase1"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sectionTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="(blank)" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/addCatButton"
            android:layout_width="33dp"
            android:layout_height="33dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:layout_gravity="right"            
            android:background="@drawable/plusicon3"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="#b5b5b5"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/listview_style_list_selector" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Whats wrong? Thanks

Comment: You want only LinearLayout...or I can make a RelativeLayout to show you as example...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`layout_gravity` only defines the position of your TextView in the parent `LinearLayout`. As your `TextView` width is set to `match_parent`, the `TextView` cannot be centered as you would expect.

Use `gravity` instead of `layout_gravity`. This will directly center the text in the TextView, not the TextView as a whole.

This is the full code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/mLlayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:background="@color/BlueOcean"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sectionOptionsButton"
        android:layout_width="33dp"
        android:layout_height="33dp"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:layout_gravity="left"            
        android:background="@drawable/adddatabase1"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sectionTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="(blank)" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addCatButton"
        android:layout_width="33dp"
        android:layout_height="33dp"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:layout_gravity="right"            
        android:background="@drawable/plusicon3"/>
</LinearLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="#b5b5b5"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/listview_style_list_selector" />
```

Comment: i probably didnt explained it well. I want to center the view in the parent viewgroup. thats what im not being able to accomplish

Comment: I have this: [Button][TextView]   [Button]. I want [Button]   [TextView]   [Button]

Comment: Have you tried my code? I fixed problem now. It should work for the issue you explained.

Comment: It works. I already tried it, but i unistalled it and tried it again and now works like a charm. Awesome. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this way:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/mLlayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:background="@color/BlueOcean"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sectionOptionsButton"
        android:layout_width="33dp"
        android:layout_height="33dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left"            
        android:background="@drawable/adddatabase1"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sectionTitle"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="(blank)" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addCatButton"
        android:layout_width="33dp"
        android:layout_height="33dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"            
        android:background="@drawable/plusicon3"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: unfortunately its still the same

Comment: @BrunoCarvalho you want to align the text inside the textview or the textview itself?

Comment: i want the textview itselft. I want to have button1-aligned left, textview-center and button2-aligned right